# Memory allocation with unknown number of elements

Tags: c++, new-operator

Since the number of elements is determined by some conditions, I wrote a program like this;

```
    int i = 0;
    int *layer;
    while (i != 12){
        layer = new int;
        layer[i] = i;
        cout << layer[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    delete[] layer;
    return 0;
```

I get the result;

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

And then program crashes. What is the reason of this and how should I modify the program in order to allocate memory for unknown number of elements?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *undefined behaviour*. You allocate space for a single `int`, then you treat it as an array.

```
layer = new int; // single int
layer[i] = i;    // wat??
```

Then you leak the memory, then you call `delete[]` on the last newed `int`. Since it isn't clear what you want to do with your code, I can only offer some suggestions:

- Consider using [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as a dynamic array. It will save you *a lot* of trouble.
- If you must allocate an array with `new` (you probably don't), you need `new int[n]` where `n` is the number of elements.
- Call `delete []` for every `new[]` and `delete` for every `new`.

Comment: Okey, I may use vector but is there a way to allocate memory for next one at each time?

Comment: You can either create a vector with a given size, or `push_back` elements into it, increasing its size by one each time.